# Help! I forgot my password!

Tags: code-golf, math

Help! I just logged into Stack Exchange, but I forgot what my password is! I need a way to work it out before I log off.

Luckily, I'm an excellent hacker. Not only was I able to find my password's hash, but I also found Stack Exchange's hashing algorithm! It takes the ASCII value of each digit multiplied by that digit's place, then sums all those values together. For example:

```
"135" -> 1*49 + 2*51 + 3*53 = 310
```

I remember that my password is 3 digits long, and that each character is a number between 0 and 5 inclusive (such that it will match the regex: `^[0-5]{3}$`), but that's still too many possibilities to guess. I need a program that can convert a hash back into potential passwords, but despite being an expert hacker, I can't code to save my life! I was able to write these tests out by hand though:

```
input -> output
288   -> 000                      // lowest possible hash
290   -> 200, 010
298   -> 022, 050, 103, 131, 212, 240, 321, 402, 430, 511   
318   -> 555                      // highest possible hash
```

Can one of you write a program for me that will take in a hash and print all the possible passwords I could have used?

The input will always be able to produce at least one valid password. Any output format is allowed, as long as the strings can be clearly identified. I'm also not concerned about leading zeroes, so if a potential password is `001`, I'll also accept `01` or `1`.

Please help me from being locked out of Stack Exchange!

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins!

Comment: Isn't `1`'s Ascii value `49` instead of `48`?

Comment: And 3 is 51 as well.

Comment: Whoops, thanks I fixed that. I think my test cases are still ok though.

Comment: @LordFarquaad test cases look fine but example should be `"135" -> 1*49 + 2*51 + 3*53 = 310`

Comment: _must be delimited by a comma (a comma followed by one or more spaces is ok too)_ Why the restrictive output format? We usualy allow flexible formats

Comment: @LuisMendo honestly, because this is my first code golf question. I don't really know the standard for specifying how a list should be outputted. How would you normally say it? Would you just not address it and it's understood? I can make an edit, but I don't want to mess up the existing answers.

Comment: The usual here is to say something like "any ouput format is allowed, as long as the strings can be clearly identified". Or maybe allow any non-numeric separator. If you change it, notify current answerers with a comment in their answer

Comment: outputing `54` instead of `054` is acceptable?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Yep, leading zeroes are optional. I remember I used 3 digits, so if I just see `54` I can work out the zeroes in front.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
5Ý3ãʒÇƶOQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f9PBc48OLT0063H5sm3/g//9GlhYA)

Returns list of lists of digits.

Comment: That makes for a pretty decent password.

Answer (score 9):

## [C](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>113</s> 108 bytes

```
f(int h){int i=47,j,k;while(++i<54)for(j=47;++j<54)for(k=47;++k<54;)if(h==i+j+j+k*3)printf("%c%c%c",i,j,k);}
```

It is unique to see what is meant for output, the output is of the format: 200010

All passwords are written as 3-digits without delimiter.

Comment: Hey, code I can read!  Nice contrast to Jelly and such.  +1 for using a classic language.  :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ṿ€Oæ.J
6Ḷṗ3Ç⁼¥Ðf
```

A monadic link returning a list of lists of digits.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4bm@4oKsT8OmLkoKNuG4tuG5lzPDh@KBvMKlw5Bm////Mjkw)**

#### How?

```
Ṿ€Oæ.J - Link 1, hash: list of integers (the digits of a password)
Ṿ€     - unevaluate €ach (giving a list of characters)
  O    - cast to ordinals (Ṿ€O could actually be replaced with +48 too)
     J - range of length (i.e. [1,2,3] in all use-cases)
   æ.  - dot product

6Ḷṗ3Ç⁼¥Ðf - Main link: number, n
6Ḷ        - lowered range of 6 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
  ṗ3      - Cartesian power with 3 = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],...,[5,5,5]] (all passwords)
       Ðf - filter keep if:
      ¥   -   last two links as a dyad (right implicitly n):
    Ç     -     call last link (1) as a monad
     ⁼    -     equals right?
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>126</s> 75 bytes

-2 thanks to @ArnoldPalmer

```python
lambda h:[(P/36,P%36/6,P%6)for P in range(216)if P/36+P%36/6*2+P%6*3==h&31]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BDoIwDIbP8BS9KAxJEJYsSsIRr3LwJh4mbkKCYykjwtPjpp7ar/3aXy@mHVS2yqJee/66Pzi0@TWsEsriakNZ4gojckCooFOAXD1FmKWMdBKctftZUWYbFtGiaLc0va0Gl9z33m3XC7jgJCx4MxT2hZ5MSCxp7JSBoFZBDLNlF8Hje9y4GBnOxJ38re/cF3MjtIHyfCoRB7R7zcdxpenez46HDw)

Comment: If you replace both `P/6/6`'s with `P/36`, you save 2 bytes

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to write, +1

Comment: @Felipe Nardi Batista, [I don't know why that would be the case](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8jQTNOKizMzTSFT39hMQdEWSJvpmwGFOAuKMvNKFDL//wcA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 20 bytes

```
'0':'5'3Z^t3:*!si=Y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X91A3UrdVN04Kq7E2EpLsTjTNlLz/38jSwsA)

#### Explanation

```
'0':'5'   % Push inclusive range from '0' to '5', that is, '012345'
3Z^       % Cartesian power with exponent 3. Each Cartesian tuple is a row
t         % Duplicate
3:        % Push [1 2 3]
*         % Multiply element-wise with broadcast
!s        % Sum of each row
i         % Input number
=         % Logical mask of values that equal the input
Y)        % Use as logical index into the rows of the matrix. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 81 bytes

```python
lambda h:[(a,b,c)for a in r for b in r for c in r if a+2*b+3*c+288==h]
r=range(6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY2xDoIwFEVn@Iq30QKDQmIISUdcXdzEodRim2BpHiXC12OLJm73vPtujl2dGk2x9azdBv7qHhxUfSM873JB@xGBgzaAEGL3j@IbdQ88K9IuK1ORFVXFmLrHyJCbpyQnujlc6zh6Kz1IuOIsPUQLMD@2syPUk0VtHCStSXJYPO/KIA@Cniw0TH5f@z2Wi5DWQXM5N4gj@t7yadrK4@ED)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>71</s> <s>70</s> <s>64</s> 61 bytes

```
l=[0..5]
f p=[show=<<[a,b,c]|a<-l,b<-l,c<-l,p-288==a+2*b+3*c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8c22kBPzzSWK02hwDa6OCO/3NbGJjpRJ0knObYm0UY3RycJRCSDiAJdIwsLW9tEbSOtJG1jreTY/7mJmXkKtgop@VwKCgoFRZl5JQoqCmkKQGVoApYG6AJoKowNLf4DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Challenger5*

```
{:H;6Zm*{s:i3,:).*:+H=},}
```

Anonymous block expecting the hash on the stack (as an integer) and leaves the result on the stack (as a list of strings).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1flPm/2srD2iwqV6u62CrTWMdKU0/LStvDtlan9n9dwX8jSwMA)

#### Explanation

```
:H;    e# Store the hash in H.
6Zm*   e# 3rd Cartesian power of [0 1 2 3 4 5].
{      e# For each tuple in the power:
 s     e#  Stringify the tuple.
 :i    e#  Get the code point of each digit.
 3,:)  e#  Push [1 2 3].
 .*    e#  Element-wise multiplication of the two lists.
 :+    e#  Sum the result.
 H=    e#  Check if it's equal to the hash.
},     e# Filter the tuples to only ones for which this block gave a truthy result.
```

Comment: @LordFarquaad Oh, uh... I didn't even see that in the first place so I guess that's fortunate

Comment: `{:H;6Zm*{s:i3,:).*:+H=},}` is 1 byte shorter. It uses digit strings in the filter rather than numbers as to use `m*`'s automatic range.

Comment: @Challenger5 Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform),<strike>133 131 125</strike> 123 bytes

```cs
n=>{int i,j,k;for(i=48;i<54;++i)for(j=48;j<54;++j)for(k=48;k<54;++k)if(i+j*2+k*3==n)Console.Write($"{i%48}{j%48}{k%48},");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcuxCsIwGATgPU8RRCGxVdRWqKQRxFUnB@cSY/mTmmATBQl99mrq5OJyHN9xws2EbWX/cGBqfHo5L28MiaZyDt8Dcr7yIPDTwgUfKzCEBrQTHqwpwfhtzXvDt@FTMaQq1exqWwI8LxiU65wlCdAoKor6ihpER9Ff0RSuBBI1XSV6mnFu6N4aZxs5P7fgJRmPAkzyogtqSB0zHVHW9QzVZFUUlKGfxwGMJHQYN4t/459ntoxj1/Vv)

Comment: I gave more thorough advice previously, but I didn't get it to work right. For now my simple optimization is to use `Console.Write($"{i%48}{j%48}{k%48},");` for output rather than building a return value, and removing the unnecessary brackets around the if statement to save 8 bytes.

Comment: I tried that option previously, but the Lambda requires a return value. Removing the brackets will work though. Thanks :)

Comment: The lambda requires a return value if you define it as `Func<int,string>`, but if you define it as `Action<int>` then it doesn't expect a return value.

Comment: Did not realize that! I am new to both c# and golfing, but decided to try it out when I have nothing else to do at work. Thanks again for the tips. I greatly appreaciate them.

Comment: You can get rid of the parentheses around `n`

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by declaring the variables inside the first loop: `for(int i=48,j,k;i<54;++i)`

Comment: Also by incrementing the counters in the condition you can save another 3 bytes. Eg: `for(j=47;++j<54;)`

Comment: In C# answers you must include every `using` statement, so you must either modify the answer to use `System.Console...` or add `using System;` to the byte count. Welcome to PPCG and glad to see you have chosen C# as your language!

Comment: If you play with the ambiguity between `char` and `int` in C#, you can declare your iteration variables as `char` in the first loop and still do the hash calculation exactly as you do while simplifying the `Console.Write()` sentence. Thus you can get a proper 119-byte solution. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc29CsIwFIbhPVdRujQxWv@hkqYgrjo5OJcY9TQ1wSQIUnrttS3FTXR9zst3hJsIY2Ujyty54FEh53MPIngaOAeHHDQmFTq@nJf3eCs8GJ2C9tmVN5pn1cVYLG65DYBH02hcjBWjFNL1ipHuVHTaSvERNYjqBS4YaDFaUDVacq7J8GdntDOljE8WvNyDljgMaRtSRVjdMHTFiyQhDH3NSd9sZn80v3eW866p6@YN "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 72 bytes

```
n=>[for(i of s="012345")for(j of s)for(k of s)if(n-i-j*2-k*3==288)i+j+k]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
Ｆ⁶Ｆ⁶Ｆ⁶¿⁼⁺℅Ｉι⁺×℅Ｉκ²×℅Ｉλ³Ｉθ«ＩιＩκＩλ⸿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmWPGrchk4f2P2rc86hx16OW1vd7Vp7bCWQeng7l7Dq0Cc7efWgziNpxaDVYGVgaLP5ox/7//40sLQA)

A similar approach to other answers: loop thrice from 0 to 5, calculate the hash and print the state of the iteration variables if it coincides with the input hash.

Link to the [verbose version](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw0yTS0EBwUJlKyhkpilouBaWJuYUazimpGjkF6VoOCcWl2hkamrqKIBEQjJzU4sR4tlAcSOgFJpwDlDYWBOkB8wtBDIVqqFWKCgEFGXmlcDNtcYmno1DPAdTXCmmSAkuWPv/v5GlxX/dsv@6xTkA).

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 162 Bytes

```
static void f(int n){for(int i=48;i<54;i++){for(int j=48;j<54;j++){for(int k=48;k<54;k++){if(i+j*2+k*3==n)System.out.println((char)i+""+(char)j+""+(char)k);}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>67</s> <s>62</s> 61 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam*

```r
b=t(t(expand.grid(rep(list(0:5),3))));b[b%*%1:3==scan()-288,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8m2RKNEI7WiIDEvRS@9KDNFoyi1QCMns7hEw8DKVFPHWBMIrJOik1S1VA2tjG1ti5MT8zQ0dY0sLHRi/xtZGvwHAA)

reads the number from `stdin`; returns a matrix where the rows are the characters.

It generates all possible trios of digits in a matrix format (`b`), computes the matrix product `b * [1,2,3]`, takes the rows of `b` which match (subtracting `288` from the input which is `1*48+2*28+3*48`) and returns them.

Comment: `t(t(m))` is a shorthand for `as.matrix(m)`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
fqQs*VS3CMT^jkU6 3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 40 bytes

```
[0,5|[0,5|[0,5|~a+b+b+c+c+c+288=:\?a,b,c
```

### Explanation

```
[0,5|                Make a FOR loop run through the possible digits for pos 1, called a
[0,5|                Loop for #2, b
[0,5|                Loop for #3, c
                     Calculate the hash by taking a once, b twice and c thrice, 
                     and raising all to their ASCII codepoints
 a+b+b+c+c+c+288       
~               =:   IF thta is euqal to the given hash (read from cmd line)
\?a,b,c              THEN print the digits
                     (the IF and the FOR loops are auto-closed by QBIC)
```